# pathForResource doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, nsbundle

I have problem with

```
NSString *filePaht = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)ext];
```

if I used

```
NSString *filePaht = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundName" ofType:@"aiff"];
```

it's OK. but when I used

```
NSString *fileName = [[file.list objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"soundName"];
NSString *filePaht = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"aiff"];
```

It's not work

have any idea !?

Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be with `fileName`, but it is hard to tell without more code.  What is `file.list` and how is it initialized?

Comment: “It's not work” What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to guess that fileName from file.list includes the file extension.  So you are searching for "soundName.aiff.aiff" which does not exist.  Try passing @"" for type or stripping the extension from fileName:

```
fileName = [fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your Debugger Console, as it may be telling what you're doing wrong.

> ```
> [file.list objectAtIndex:index]
> ```

If you're getting an NSRangeException, it may be because `index` contains an index that is outside the bounds of the array. Remember that arrays in Cocoa are serial, not associative; if you remove an object, the indexes of all the objects that came after it will go down by 1, upholding the invariant that 0 ≤ (every valid index) < (count of objects in the array).

It could also be because [you never declared a variable named `index`](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-05/the-peril-of-the-index-function).

> ```
> NSString *fileName = [[file.list objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"soundName"];
> NSString *filePaht = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"aiff"];
> ```

If nothing is happening or you get an NSInternalInconsistencyException, it could be one of:

- `fileList` is `nil`.
- The dictionary returned from `[file.list objectAtIndex:index]` does not have an object for the key `soundName`.

If you got a “does not respond to selector” message in the Console, it may be one of:

- `file.list` is an object, but not an NSArray.
- `[file.list objectAtIndex:index]` is not an NSDictionary.
- `fileName` (`[[file.list objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"soundName"]`) is not an NSString.

Remember that the class name you use when you declare the variable doesn't matter except to the compiler; at run time, it's just a variable holding a pointer to an object. The object can be of any class. It is perfectly valid to put something that isn't an NSString into an `NSString *` variable; it simply carries a very high (near certain) risk of wrong behavior and/or crashing shortly thereafter.

Such a crash will usually manifest in the form of a “does not respond to selector” exception (after something sends the object a message that NSString objects, for example, should respond to, but that the object doesn't respond to because it isn't an NSString).

Whichever problem you're having, you can use [the Debugger](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/) to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry with my fault.
I get data from XML file
and that data include "\n". yes I see "\n" so I replace with @""
but it not enough I must trim space value again.

Thanks for all advice ^_^